# Pinpoint session duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-pinpoint

Is there any way to demonstrate users session duration on Amazon Pinpoint dashboard?
All Pinpoint events have a startTimestamp tag which shows the time for that event, but I could not find session length in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not yet supported. You can get this data by exporting the metrics to a RedShift cluster and querying the analytics data using SQL (Or exporting to S3 and processing it with EMR).

Answer (score 0):

check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSDQx5ardmI

Here are the steps:

1. Export Pinpoint app events to Kinesis
2. Dump Kinesis streams to S3
3. Create a AWS Glue crawler to generate a table from your S3 path
4. Use Athena to write SQL to analyze the session duration